# cross symbol over a mathematical term

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I am writing a presentation with beamer

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\hat{H}=\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2m})+\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2M})+\dots\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now, I want to show in my presentation that we can ignore the 2nd term `\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2M})` possibly putting a cross over it. 
So, in the next frame, I will like to have

```
\[\hat{H}=\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2m})+
\A_RED_CROSS_OVER_THIS_TERM{\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2M})}+\dots\]
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,127,0}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \[\hat{H}=\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2m})+\xcancel{\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2M})}+\dots\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Tried this, and color has not changed.

Comment: Try the package `cancel` and the command `\cancel{<expression>}` or `\xcancel{<expression>}`. You can even redefine the color if you use the `color` package and the command `\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{<color_command>}`.

Comment: @LudovicC., sorry if I was not quite clear, but I think \xcancel gives a boring X over the term. I am looking for a visually attractive red cross. i.e. \xcancel with color

Comment: see my edit of the comment.

Comment: here is the documentation of the `cancel` package for you to customize the display of the cross http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cancel/cancel.pdf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The definition of `\CancelColor` does not take a color but a color command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,127,0}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \[\hat{H}=\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2m})+\xcancel{\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2M})}+\dots\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,127,0}
\begin{document}
\def\x{\displaystyle\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2M})}
\begin{frame}
  \[\hat{H}=\sum(-\frac{\nabla_i^2}{2m})+\stackengine{-.3ex}{$\x$}%
{\hstretch{3}{\scalerel*{\textcolor{red}{\times}}{\x}}}%
{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}%
+\dots\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One advantage to using this approach is that the crossout material can be anything.  Changing the `\hstretch` from 3 to 0.6 and changing `\times` to something else gives

[image]

Make sure you have V2.0 of stackengine, available at ctan.org